# JDBC, help displaying result set as a table in Java GUI

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, jdbc, jtable

I'm working on a program (in Java) that is supposed to display a GUI that allows a user to put in an SQL query and once the execute button is clicked, the result set should show as a table on the GUI. I can see the initial outline of the blank table, but the table won't update once the query is executed. I'm very new to Java GUIs so I could be making a really dumb mistake. I thought that maybe I'm just displaying a blank uneditable scroll pane and not the actual table, but I'm not so sure anymore. I honestly have no idea where I'm messing it up.

I'm pretty sure the clear button will be similar to the execute button except I need to create a blank table and then display that on there. I just can't get the table to update lol. Anyways, I'm getting off topic. I'll paste the code I have below. There are 2 classes pasted below. One called QueryGUI and the other called ResultTable. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Is there anything I can do to make this easier to help me with? I've been staring at Google, Oracle's site, and other threads on this site for hours and I have no clue why the table won't update/show.

EDIT2: Figured it out, I was trying to set the model to my scroll pane and not my JTable, that's why it wasn't working.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class QueryGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static ResultTable tableModel;

private static String[] jdbcDriverStrings = {"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "com.ibm.db2.jdbc.netDB2Driver",
    "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "com.jdbc.odbc.jdbcOdbcDriver"};
private static String[] dbURLStrings = {"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project4", "jdbc://localhost3306/bikedb",
"jdbc:mysql://localhost3306/test"};

static String JDBC_DRIVER = null;
static String DATABASE_URL = null;
static String USERNAME = null;
static String PASSWORD = null;
static String QUERY = null;
private static JComboBox driverList = new JComboBox(jdbcDriverStrings);
private static JComboBox dbURLList = new JComboBox(dbURLStrings);
private static JTextField usernameField = new JTextField(20);
private static JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
private static JTable resultTable = new JTable(tableModel); // create JTable delegate for tableModel 
private static JTextArea sqlCommandEntry = new JTextArea(7, 30);
private static JScrollPane scrollingSQLCommandEntry = new JScrollPane(
        sqlCommandEntry, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
private static JLabel connectionLabel = new JLabel("No Connection Now");

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SQL Client GUI - (MJL)");
    pane.setLayout(null);

    //Create all the labels, combo boxes, buttons, and text fields/areas
    JLabel comboAndTextLabel = new JLabel("Enter Database Information");
    JLabel driverLabel = new JLabel("JDBC Driver");
    JLabel dbURLLabel = new JLabel("Database URL");
    JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JLabel SQLEntryLabel = new JLabel("Enter SQL Command");
    JLabel SQLResultLabel = new JLabel("SQL Execution Result");
    JButton connectButton = new JButton("Connect to Database");
    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear Command");
    JButton executeButton = new JButton("Execute SQL Command");
    JButton clearResultButton = new JButton("Clear Result Window");


    JScrollPane sqlResultArea = new JScrollPane(resultTable);
    //scrollingSQLCommandEntry.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    //scrollingSQLCommandEntry.setLineWrap(true);

    pane.add(driverList);
    pane.add(dbURLList);
    pane.add(comboAndTextLabel);
    pane.add(driverLabel);
    pane.add(dbURLLabel);
    pane.add(usernameLabel);
    pane.add(passwordLabel);
    pane.add(usernameField);
    pane.add(passwordField);
    pane.add(SQLEntryLabel);
    pane.add(scrollingSQLCommandEntry);
    pane.add(connectionLabel); 
    pane.add(connectButton);
    pane.add(clearButton);
    pane.add(executeButton);
    pane.add(SQLResultLabel);
    pane.add(sqlResultArea);
    pane.add(clearResultButton);
    //pane.add(new JScrollPane(resultTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);


    driverList.addActionListener(driverList);
    dbURLList.addActionListener(dbURLList);

    Insets insets = pane.getInsets();
    //The next giant block of code takes each component and moves them to the
    //desired space on the GUI. It uses absolute positioning
    //This section moves the 5 labels on the top left
    Dimension size = comboAndTextLabel.getPreferredSize();
    comboAndTextLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = driverLabel.getPreferredSize();
    driverLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 26 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = dbURLLabel.getPreferredSize();
    dbURLLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 54 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = usernameLabel.getPreferredSize();
    usernameLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 80 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = passwordLabel.getPreferredSize();
    passwordLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 105 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);

    //This section moves the combo boxes and the text fields on the top left
    size = driverList.getPreferredSize();
    driverList.setBounds(90 + insets.left, 22 + insets.top,
            size.width + 90, size.height);
    size = dbURLList.getPreferredSize();
    dbURLList.setBounds(90 + insets.left, 51 + insets.top,
            size.width + 65, size.height);
    size = usernameField.getPreferredSize();
    usernameField.setBounds(90 + insets.left, 80 + insets.top,
            size.width + 73, size.height);
    size = passwordField.getPreferredSize();
    passwordField.setBounds(90 + insets.left, 104 + insets.top,
            size.width + 73, size.height);

    //This section moves the label and text area on the top right
    size = SQLEntryLabel.getPreferredSize();
    SQLEntryLabel.setBounds(425 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = scrollingSQLCommandEntry.getPreferredSize();
    scrollingSQLCommandEntry.setBounds(425 + insets.left, 24 + insets.top,
            size.width - 1, size.height + 4);
    //Puts a border around the text area on the right
    sqlCommandEntry.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));

    //Moves the connection status label and 3 middle buttons, also sets label color to red 
    size = connectionLabel.getPreferredSize();
    connectionLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    connectionLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 180 + insets.top,
            size.width + 175, size.height);
    size = connectButton.getPreferredSize();
    connectButton.setBounds(297 + insets.left, 175 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = clearButton.getPreferredSize();
    clearButton.setBounds(456 + insets.left, 175 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = executeButton.getPreferredSize();
    executeButton.setBounds(588 + insets.left, 175 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);

    //Moves SQL execution label and text area as well as clear result window button
    size = SQLResultLabel.getPreferredSize();
    SQLResultLabel.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 200 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);
    size = sqlResultArea.getPreferredSize();
    sqlResultArea.setBounds(8 + insets.left, 217 + insets.top,
            size.width + 295, size.height - 177);
    //puts border around result text area   
    resultTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    size = clearResultButton.getPreferredSize();
    clearResultButton.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 451 + insets.top,
            size.width, size.height);

    connectButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    try {
                        char[] tempPass = null;
                        USERNAME = usernameField.getText();
                        tempPass = passwordField.getPassword();
                        PASSWORD = String.valueOf(tempPass);
                        JDBC_DRIVER = (String)QueryGUI.driverList.getSelectedItem();
                        DATABASE_URL = (String)QueryGUI.dbURLList.getSelectedItem();
                        tableModel = new ResultTable(JDBC_DRIVER, DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        connectionLabel.setText("Connected to " + DATABASE_URL);
                    } 
                    catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFound){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                                "MySQL driver not found", "Driver not found",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                        System.exit(1); // terminate application
                    } 
                    catch(SQLException sqlException){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlException.getMessage(), 
                                "Database error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                        // ensure database connection is closed
                        tableModel.disconnectFromDatabase();

                        System.exit(1);   // terminate application
                    } 
                }
            }
            );

    //create event listener for executeButton
    executeButton.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener(){
                // pass query to table model
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    // perform a new query
                    try{
                        tableModel.setQuery(sqlCommandEntry.getText());
                        //These next 2 lines don't work. Bottom one line throws an eror message window
                        //stating can't execute query
                        //tableModel = new ResultTable(JDBC_DRIVER, DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        //tableModel.setUpdate(sqlCommandEntry.getText());
                    }
                    catch(SQLException sqlException){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlException.getMessage(),
                                "Database error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                    } 
                } 
            }            
            ); 
}

//JDBC Driver combo box action
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == QueryGUI.driverList){
        //JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        JDBC_DRIVER = (String)QueryGUI.driverList.getSelectedItem();            
    }
    if(e.getSource() == QueryGUI.dbURLList){
        DATABASE_URL = (String)QueryGUI.dbURLList.getSelectedItem();
    }
}

//Create the GUI and show it.
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SQL Client GUI - (MJL)");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Size and display the window.
    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setSize(785 + insets.left + insets.right,
            525 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //dispose of window when user quits application (this overrides
    // the default of HIDE_ON_CLOSE)
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    // ensure database connection is closed when user quits application
    frame.addWindowListener(
            new WindowAdapter(){
                // disconnect from database and exit when window has closed
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event){
                    tableModel.disconnectFromDatabase();
                    System.exit(0);
                } 
            } 
            ); 

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //new QueryGUI();
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is the 2nd class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ResultTable extends AbstractTableModel{
private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;
private ResultSet resultSet;
private ResultSetMetaData metaData;
private int numberOfRows;

// keep track of database connection status
private boolean connectedToDatabase = false;

// constructor initializes resultSet and obtains its meta data object;
// determines number of rows
public ResultTable(String driver, String url, 
        String username, String password) 
                throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    // load database driver class
    Class.forName(driver);

    // connect to database
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    // create Statement to query database
    statement = connection.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    // update database connection status
    connectedToDatabase = true;

    // set query and execute it
    //setQuery(query);
} 

// get class that represents column type
public Class getColumnClass(int column) throws IllegalStateException{
    // ensure database connection is available
    if(!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    // determine Java class of column
    try{
        String className = metaData.getColumnClassName(column + 1);

        // return Class object that represents className
        return Class.forName(className);
    } 
    catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return Object.class; // if problems occur above, assume type Object
} 

// get number of columns in ResultSet
public int getColumnCount() throws IllegalStateException{   
    // ensure database connection is available
    System.out.println("inside getColumnCount");
    if(!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    // determine number of columns
    try{
        return metaData.getColumnCount(); 
    } 
    catch(SQLException sqlException){
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return 0; // if problems occur above, return 0 for number of columns
} 

// get name of a particular column in ResultSet
public String getColumnName(int column) throws IllegalStateException{    
    // ensure database connection is available
    if(!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    // determine column name
    try{
        return metaData.getColumnName(column + 1);  
    } 
    catch(SQLException sqlException){
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return ""; // if problems, return empty string for column name
} 

// return number of rows in ResultSet
public int getRowCount() throws IllegalStateException{      
    // ensure database connection is available
    if(!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    return numberOfRows;
} 

// obtain value in particular row and column
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) throws IllegalStateException{
    // ensure database connection is available
    if(!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    // obtain a value at specified ResultSet row and column
    try{
        resultSet.next();  /* fixes a bug in MySQL/Java with date format */
        resultSet.absolute( row + 1 );
        return resultSet.getObject( column + 1 );
    } 
    catch(SQLException sqlException){
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return ""; // if problems, return empty string object
} 

// set new database query string
public void setQuery(String query) 
        throws SQLException, IllegalStateException{
    // ensure database connection is available
    if(!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    // specify query and execute it
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    // obtain meta data for ResultSet
    metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

    // determine number of rows in ResultSet
    resultSet.last();                   // move to last row
    numberOfRows = resultSet.getRow();  // get row number      

    // notify JTable that model has changed
    fireTableStructureChanged();
} 


// set new database update-query string - this isn't working presently.
//Gives me an error message saying "Cannot issue select".
/*public void setUpdate(String query) 
        throws SQLException, IllegalStateException{
    int res;
    // ensure database connection is available
    if (!connectedToDatabase) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");

    // specify query and execute it
    res = statement.executeUpdate(query);

    // notify JTable that model has changed
    fireTableStructureChanged();
} */

// close Statement and Connection               
public void disconnectFromDatabase(){              
    if (!connectedToDatabase)                  
        return;

    // close Statement and Connection            
    try{                                            
        statement.close();                        
        connection.close();                       
    }                                  
    catch(SQLException sqlException){                                            
        sqlException.printStackTrace();           
    }              
    finally{   // update database connection status                                            
        connectedToDatabase = false;              
    } 
}           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great effort.  However, there is a lot of code that you are troubleshooting at once.  If you would like to get help sooner in the future than I would recommend throwing out everything that isn't really necessary.  For example, you could probably throw out all of the components of your GUI except the JTable.

*Ultimately, I believe your problem is that you are creating your JTable statically.  At the time you create it your TableModel has not been initialized and so it is set to NULL.  Later, when you do initialize your TableModel, it will not update the JTable's reference (it will still be set to null).*

I would recommend creating your JTable with the empty consturctor and then calling setModel after you construct your TableModel.

In addition, I would highly recommend that you get this reviewed by an experienced developer if you have one available (StackOverflow isn't really designed for that).  While it is clear you have spent a great deal of effort on this there are a number of things in here that make the code hard to read and maintain and she could help explain the reasoning behind those issues.

For example:

- You have a lot of static variables, this tends to lead to untestable code.
- Absolute positioning tends to be discouraged in GUI development.
- You are connecting to the database and performing lots of blocking I/O in the Swing event thread.
- Your connection is staying active for the lifetime of the application, this could become a drain on resources and typically you would want to use a connection pool or have short lived connections.